# Obtaining the last level of a json tree on php

Tags: php, json, schema.org

I have a json tree with categories,

I would like to obtain the last level of elements for each different category.

For example on this json:

```
 [
    {
      "category_id": "3",
      "parent_id": "2",
      "name": "Women",
      "categories": [
        {
          "category_id": "11",
          "parent_id": "3",
          "name": "Clothing",
          "categories": [
            {
              "category_id": "30",
              "parent_id": "11",
              "name": "T-shirts",
              "categories": null
            },
            {
              "category_id": "33",
              "parent_id": "11",
              "name": "jeans",
              "categories": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category_id": "5",
      "parent_id": "2",
      "name": "Footwear ",
      "categories": [
        {
          "category_id": "15",
          "parent_id": "5",
          "name": "Rings",
          "categories": [
            {
              "category_id": "51",
              "parent_id": "15",
              "name": "Small Leathers",
              "categories": null
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "category_id": "16",
          "parent_id": "5",
          "name": "Bands",
          "categories": [
            {
              "category_id": "41",
              "parent_id": "16",
              "name": "boots",
              "categories": null
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "category_id": "48",
          "parent_id": "5",
          "name": "Bracelets",
          "categories": [
            {
              "category_id": "55",
              "parent_id": "48",
              "name": "Cocktail",
              "categories": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

The result would be an array (T-shirts, Jeans, Small Leathers, boots, cocktail)

What I was thinking is to decode it on an array and search filter the array with all the categories that are null, but I'm not sure if it's the best option because the object have different levels.

(I'm sorry for the English)

Comment: well, yeah. you'd have to decode it first. php doesn't know what json is. it's just a blob of text. and yes, you can use an array_filter() with an appropriate recursive callback to scan the array, but returning matches from that recursive call will be interesting if you need to preserve the "path" you take through the array to find the matched node(s).

Comment: right now I wont preserve the path, because I'm using this to match my own tree on another endpoint, but I don't know if doing the filter would be the best practice or if it's better to use a recursive function and not asuming the null field

Comment: That's not even valid JSON and I don't know who is going to the trouble of trying to fix it to test an answer.

Comment: @AbraCadaver it's a valid code, it just had a "categories": on the top which depending on the standard is or not valid :), I took it out to avoid confusions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json string is not a valid. It can be made valid by enclosing the json string in {}.

```
$json = '{"categories": [
{
  "category_id": "3",
  "parent_id": "2",
  "name": "Women",
  "categories": [
    {
      "category_id": "11",
      "parent_id": "3",
      "name": "Clothing",
      "categories": [
        {
          "category_id": "30",
          "parent_id": "11",
          "name": "T-shirts",
          "categories": null
        },
        {
          "category_id": "33",
          "parent_id": "11",
          "name": "jeans",
          "categories": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "category_id": "5",
  "parent_id": "2",
  "name": "Footwear ",
  "categories": [
    {
      "category_id": "15",
      "parent_id": "5",
      "name": "Rings",
      "categories": [
        {
          "category_id": "51",
          "parent_id": "15",
          "name": "Small Leathers",
          "categories": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category_id": "16",
      "parent_id": "5",
      "name": "Bands",
      "categories": [
        {
          "category_id": "41",
          "parent_id": "16",
          "name": "boots",
          "categories": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category_id": "48",
      "parent_id": "5",
      "name": "Bracelets",
      "categories": [
        {
          "category_id": "55",
          "parent_id": "48",
          "name": "Cocktail",
          "categories": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]}';
```

Decode the json string in to php opject

```
$json_object = json_decode($json);
```

Use this recursive function to fetch get all the last level categories in a array.

```
function getLastCategories($object){
        $last_categories = array();
        if(is_array($object->categories)){
            foreach($object->categories as $categories){
                $last_categories = array_merge( $last_categories, getLastCategories($categories));
            }
        }else{
            $last_categories[]=$object->name;
        }
        return $last_categories;
    }

print_r(getLastCategories($json_object));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => T-shirts
    [1] => jeans
    [2] => Small Leathers
    [3] => boots
    [4] => Cocktail
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using recursive iterators.

```
$categories = json_decode($json);

// create the iterator    
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($categories));

// iterate recursively    
foreach ($iterator as $key => $subcategories) {

    // if the 'categories' key is empty for the current level...
    if ($key == 'categories' && !$subcategories) {

        // then add the value of the 'name' key for the current level to your result array.
        $result[] = $iterator->getSubIterator()->offsetGet('name');
    }
}
```

This may not be the most efficient way to do it, but it makes the code pretty simple.